# How to give feedback on a course when no evaluation was offered?

Tags: ethics, evaluation

I just finished a course in organic chemistry this semester, where we had absolutely everything go wrong. Our TA had immigration problems, and only showed up to the first few days. Our stockroom was mostly always empty of chemicals, and most of us didn't have enough glassware. Our fume hoods stopped working, and the list goes on and on.

A lot of the students had been looking forward to the course evaluation, to express our frustration of having to teach ourselves organic chemistry, and lab techniques without any supervision.

However, on the final day, after we took our final exam, which was given by the supervising professor, we were not offered a course evaluation.

I'm wondering if there's some kind of protocol for giving feedback to the chemistry department, as I don't know who is even aware of what went on in our class. I also do not want to come off like a whiner.

Also, the professor seems to be giving a huge curve to try to stave off a revolution. For example, I scored a 99% in the class, and my lab partner got a 72%, and we both walked away with an "A", which is even more frustrating.

Comment: Write to the department. Do so anonymously, if you wish.

Comment: Also look up your school or department policy on this.  I suspect they have something in place.

Comment: In order to avoid appearing to be a whiner, find a couple of positive things to say.  If there's *nothing* positive to say about this particular course, then broaden your write-up as much as necessary so you can say something sincerely positive about *something*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, the dean of each department is the person who has the ability and the know-how of each professor to actually effect some change. That changes by school and by department, but you can't go wrong by finding your dean's office and dropping in or sending an email. I've done it before and action was taken very quickly, but I happened to be a part of a very well-structured department with passionate staff.